# Timing javascript animations: slower at the end then it should

Tags: javascript, css, animation, requestanimationframe

I am encountering a problem while trying to make Javascript animations. I hope you guys could help me out, because I can't find a similar question on Stackoverflow or on another website. WARNING: I like writing, so perhaps this topic is a bit long and I am sorry for that. I just want to make everything clear. TL;DR version is at the bottom of this post.

**What am I trying to make?**
I am building my own Javascript library (for learning purposes, therefore I don't want to use jQuery or any other library for this problem). The library has a lot of functions, and animations are one of them. An animations is a change of the CSS of a specific element, but in a smooth way. Imagine you have an element's width of `200px` and you want to make it `400px`, it looks a lot better if that doesn't change abrubtly, but rather gently. I managed to make animations, so that's not the problem.

**What is my problem?**
Animations have a specific timeframe. Within this timeframe the css changes from one value to an other value. The timeframe, like I made it, has the next calculation:

```
let timeFraction = (time - start) / this.duration;
```

where `start` is the starting time the `animate()` method is called (you'll see the code in a bit). Time is the time while the animation is running, and when time and start differ the ammount of the `duration`, the animation is finished.
The `timeFraction` is the ammount of time that is passed since the animation is called. This ammount is multiplied with the to be changed css value. This sounds a bit weird, I know, so let me give an example:

I want to change, again, the ammount from `200px` to `400px`. The difference between these two values is `200px`. So the element has to change this value.
The animation timeframe is 3000ms. So the animation has to be completed in 3 seconds. 1,5 seconds are past (the half of 3s), and then the half of the `200px` should be added up the the existing width of `200px`.

```
let timeFraction = (1500 - 0) / 3000; // is 0.5
let cssAdded = timeFraction * 200; // 100px
```

So when 3s are past, `timeFraction` should be `1`, and that will be the full `200px`.
This works like a charm. The animation runs smooth, but when it is about to end, the animation gets a lot slower. Here is an example:

[See a GIF](https://gyazo.com/5519b592864b8b18ae3102a4a0ae6405)

while the calculation is still the same. I just want it to change smootly until the timeframe has past.

**What is my code?**
I am working with EcmaScript 6 and vanilla JS.

The animate method:

```
animate(css) {
    if(this !== undefined && css) {
        this.css = css;
    }

    let start = performance.now();

    requestAnimationFrame(function animate(time) {
        let timeFraction = (time - start) / this.duration;

        if( timeFraction > 1 ) timeFraction = 1;

        let timing = this.timer(timeFraction);

        this.draw(timing);

        if ( timing < 1 ) {
            requestAnimationFrame(animate.bind(this));
        }
    }.bind(this));
}
```

The timer method:

```
timer(timeFraction) {
    return timeFraction;
}
```

The draw method:

```
draw(timing) {
    for(let property in this.css) {

        let newValue = window.getComputedStyle(this.element)[property];
        let match = /\d+(px|em|%|rem)/.exec(newValue);

        if(match !== null) {
            newValue = match[0].replace(match[1], '');
            this.element.style[property] = Math.floor(parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(this.element)[property].replace('px', '')) - (timing * (newValue - parseInt(this.css[property].replace('px', ''))))) + match[1];
        }
        else {
            this.element.style[property] -= timing * (window.getComputedStyle(this.element)[property] - this.css[property]);
        }
    }
}
```

**What did I try?**
First of all I tried to search examples of people making javascript animations. I tried their way of calculating the css within the timeframe of the animation, but the problem wasn't solved. I tried changing `performance.now()` to `new Date().getTime()` and calculated further from there, but still the same problem occured. So I don't know why the animation isn't always at the same speed, while it should be. Can you guys please help?

**TL;DR version**
I am making animations in Javascript. The animations are linear (always at the same speed) but it occures that the animation is slower at the end of the animation (see the GIF in this topic).

**My concrete question**
Why is the animation slower at the end? What has to do with that? The calculation I explained above or something else? Or am I missing something important? Please help, because I don't know what is causing this.

Comment: It looks like it's recalculating the time at each frame with `(time - start) / this.duration` and when you call `timer` the number is larger and larger each time as `time` gets farther from `start`

Comment: [Your timing function graphed](https://jsfiddle.net/hovu5jvq/). That looks  linear as long as the animation frame is running in a timely fashion. Perhaps your problem is in the logic for manipulating the CSS values.

Comment: Have you tried using the timeline in  devtools under performance tab to see if the dom is not doing something to slow you down. I can not see anything wrong with the code you have supplied, well that depends on how much you are iterating in the CSS object, And what is the point of `timer(timeFraction) {
    return timeFraction;
}`???

Comment: Just got the gif. Does the animation work when you have the dev tools closed. Dev tools can have a bad effect on performance.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments! @PatrickBarr: that's right. I has to calculate the time that has past. So time needs to get further from start while the time is ticking. @Dark Falcon: It indeed looks linear. So probably my calculation is correct then. I think the problem does lie in the CSS manipulation then. @Blindman67: That is just for testing purpose. `this.timer` has a bunch of calculations to make `ease-in`, `ease-out`, etc work. And with dev-tools closed the problem is still there, but thanks for the advice!

Comment: Could you put your code into a working code snippet, as concise as possible while fully functioning? This is the kind of question that needs to be answered! I want to be sure I'm working with your exact situation

Comment: I figured it out myself, but I have no idea whether I am alowed to answer my own question. Or do I have to edit my question so people can learn from it?

Comment: You are definitely allowed to answer your own question. It's encouraged. Everything that helps anyone learn anything is encouraged!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out why the animation was slower in the end than in the beginning.

As I stated in my question, there is a calculation made every time the `draw` method was called. Again, this calculation checked the difference between the existing css property to be animated and multiplied the `timing` variable (the `timing` variable holds the timeframe of animation. So when the half of the animation time is passed, `timing` is equal to 0.5, when the animation is complete, `timing` is 1).

But because the difference is calculated **every** time the `draw` method is called, the difference is different every time. In the end, when the animation is almost complete, that difference is very small. And while the difference gets smaller, `timing * difference` gets smaller too.
This results in a smaller difference to be added every time. (so even from the beginning it gets slower, but you won't notice it).

I changed my code to calculate the difference at the beginning of the animation and `timing` is now multiplied with that difference, instead of fetching the difference again every loop. (besides that, the code becomes a lot cleaner and easier to read/ understand.

The animate method:

```
animate(css) {
    if(typeof css === 'object') {
        for(let property in css) {
            this.cssDiff[property] = this.calculateDifference(property, css[property])
        }
    }
    else if(arguments.length === 2) {
        this.cssDiff[arguments[0]] = this.calculateDifference(arguments[0], arguments[1]);
    }
    else {
        return;
    }

    //The rest of the code, same as in my question...
}
```

The draw method:

```
draw(timing) {
    for(let property in this.cssDiff) {
        this.element.style[property] = this.cssDiff[property].start + (timing * this.cssDiff[property].value) + this.cssDiff[property].unit;
    }
}
```

And I added a method to calculate the difference:

```
calculateDifference(property, cssValue) {
    let existingCSS = window.getComputedStyle(this.element)[property];
    let match = /(\d+)(px|em|%|rem)/.exec(existingCSS);
    let differenceMap = {value: 0, unit: 0, start: 0};

    if(match !== null) {
        differenceMap.start = Number(existingCSS.replace(/px|em|%|rem/g, ''));
        differenceMap.value = Number(cssValue.replace(/px|em|%|rem/g, '')) - Number(match[1]);
        differenceMap.unit = match[2];
    }
    else {
        differenceMap.start = Number(existingCSS);
        differenceMap.value = (typeof cssValue === 'string' ? Number(cssValue.replace(/px|em|%|rem/g, '')) : cssValue) - Number(existingCSS);
    }

    return differenceMap;
}
```

This piece of code is called once for every to be animated css property, so this code will be faster then calculating the difference every animation frame.

And for onther people to lean, this is the `timer` method (as answer to the question of @Blindman67)

```
timer(timeFraction) {
    switch(this.easing) {
        case 'ease-in':
            return timeFraction * timeFraction;
            break;
        case 'ease-out':
            return timeFraction * (2 - timeFraction);
            break;
        case 'circ':
            return 1 - Math.sin(Math.acos(timeFraction));
            break;
        case 'bounce':
            for (let a = 0, b = 1; 1; a += b, b /= 2) {
                if (timeFraction >= (7 - 4 * a) / 11) {
                    return -Math.pow((11 - 6 * a - 11 * timeFraction) / 4, 2) + Math.pow(b, 2)
                }
            }
            break;
        default:
            return timeFraction;
            break;
    }
}
```

I hope other people, who want to make JS animations, find this question + answer useful. Thanks everyone for thinking with me to come up with a solution